# Natural log question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality

> Prove that for $x> 1$, $\ln(x+1) - \ln(x)< \frac{2}{x+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You could denote a function $g(x) = \ln (x+1)-\ln x-2/(x+1)$, then you can check the $g^{'}(x)$ to see whether $g(x)$ increases or not when $x>1$, then you check $g(1)$ to see whether the inequality meets or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Herein, we present a way forward that relies on pre-calculus tools only.  To that end, we proceed with a primer.**

> **PRIMER:**
>
> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263), I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm function satisfies the inequality
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\log(x)\le x-1} \tag 1$$
>
> for $x>0$.

---

Applying $(1)$, we see that for $1< x$

$$\begin{align}
\log(x+1)-\log(x)&=\log\left(1+\frac1x\right)\\\\
&\le \frac1x\\\\
&< \frac2{x+1}
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. -Mark

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\frac{2}{x+1}-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$ on $(1,+\infty)$.

Hence, $f'(x)=-\frac{2}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}}{1+\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{1-x}{x(x+1)^2}<0$, which says that $f$ is a decreasing function

and since $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=0$, we are done!